# How to debug array and object in .jade and .pug file

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js and express js I got stuck in suitation where I am passing object to .jade file  but before that I want to debug it like we use in php print_r(array), but I am trying to use console.log(object), but this didn't work for me

Requirement:

1. Print object and array in .jade and .pug file (using node and express)

code in index.js file

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  var sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM users`;

  db.query(sqlQuery, function (err, results, fields) {

    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Register - Login',
      authorised: req.session.authorised,
      fname: req.session.fname,
      users: results
    });

  });
// console.log(authorised);
});
```

Code in .jade file I tried
div

- console.log(authorised)
  div

but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  const authorised=req.session.authorised;
  const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM users`;// use const or let 

  db.query(sqlQuery, function (err, results, fields) {
    // since both the key and value are the same in the json I am using authorised from above as the value
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Register - Login',
      authorised,
      fname: req.session.fname,
      users: results
    });

  });
  console.log(authorised);
});
```